# Find duplicate values in a multidimensional array and create new multidimensional array that contains no dupes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array taken from a database:

> ```
> Array
> (
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [facility_name] => AFC Clayton Juniors
>         [day] => 15
>         [month] => Apr
>         [year] => 2016
>         [start_time] => 20
>         [end_time] => 21
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [facility_name] => AFC Clayton Juniors
>         [day] => 15
>         [month] => Apr
>         [year] => 2016
>         [start_time] => 22
>         [end_time] => 23
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [facility_name] => Chorlton Runners
>         [day] => 15
>         [month] => Apr
>         [year] => 2016
>         [start_time] => 10
>         [end_time] => 11
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [facility_name] => Chorlton Runners
>         [day] => 15
>         [month] => Apr
>         [year] => 2016
>         [start_time] => 19
>         [end_time] => 20
>     )
> )
> ```

And I need it to be nested as follows::

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [facility_name] => AFC Clayton Juniors
        [dates] => Array
               (
                    [date1] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 15 Apr 2016
                                [timeslots] => Array
                                            (
                                              [timeslot1] => Array
                                                          (
                                                            [start_time] => 20
                                                            [end_time] => 21
                                                           )
                                              [timeslot2] => Array
                                                          (
                                                            [start_time] => 22
                                                            [end_time] => 23
                                                           )
                                            )
                    [date2] => 16 Apr 2016    //etc
              )
     )
[1] => Array
    (
      [facility_name] = Chorlton Runners
      [dates] => Array //etc
    )
)
```

To elaborate: I need to have NO duplicate names in my array, and the dates that exist for the same name to be entered as new keys to the dates array that match the same name, and the same thing for time slots. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solution let's say the array taken from the databse is named `$facilities`. The code would be:

```
$noDupes = array();

foreach ($facilities as $fac) {
    $facilityIndex = -1; // The index of the facility name, -1 indicates it wasn't found.
    $dateIndex = '';     // The index of the date string, an empty string indicates it wasn't found.
    $timeslotIndex = ''; // The index of the timeslot, an empty string indicates it wasn't found.
    $facDate = "{$fac['day']} {$fac['month']} {$fac['year']}"; // The date string (dd mmm aaaa)

    foreach ($noDupes as $f => $facility) {
         if ($fac['facility_name'] == $facility['facility_name']) {
            // If the facility name was found we take the corresponding index (0, 1, 2, etc.).
            $facilityIndex = $f;

            foreach ($facility['dates'] as $d => $date) {
                if ($facDate == $date['date']) {
                    // If the date string was found we take the corresponding index (date1, date2, date3, etc.).
                    $dateIndex = $d;

                    foreach ($date['timeslots'] as $t => $timeslot) {
                        if ($fac['start_time'] == $timeslot['start_time'] && $fac['end_time'] == $timeslot['end_time']) {
                            // If the timeslot was found we take the corresponding index (timeslot1, timeslot2, timeslot3, etc.).
                            $timeslotIndex = $t;
                            break; // end timeslot loop
                        }
                    }

                    break; // end date loop
                }
            }

            break; // end facility loop
        }
    }

    if ($facilityIndex == -1) {
        // Take the new index for the date and timeslot if-statements
        $facilityIndex = count($noDupes);

        $noDupes[] = array(
            'facility_name' => $fac['facility_name'],
            'dates' => array()
        );
    }

    if ($dateIndex == '') {
        // Calculate the new index for the date (date1, date2, etc.)
        $dateNum = count($noDupes[$facilityIndex]['dates']) + 1;
        $dateIndex = "date{$dateNum}";

        $noDupes[$facilityIndex]['dates'][$dateIndex] = array(
            'date' => $facDate,
            'timeslots' => array()
        );
    }

    if ($timeslotIndex == '') {
        // Calculate the new index for the timeslot (timeslot1, timeslot2, etc.)
        $timeslotNum = count($noDupes[$facilityIndex]['dates'][$dateIndex]['timeslots']) + 1;
        $timeslotIndex = "timeslot{$timeslotNum}";

        $noDupes[$facilityIndex]['dates'][$dateIndex]['timeslots'][$timeslotIndex] = array(
            'start_time' => $fac['start_time'],
            'end_time' => $fac['end_time']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! Both for taking the time to write the algorithm and the comments. At least now I understand how this should have been done.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON array will make your task very easy, and is supported in PHP